# event.preventDefault in React gives TypeError: event is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a React component called `App` that should display something based on a HTML form. Each time the user submits the form, the state of `App` should adapt. At first I implemented my class like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {technologies: [], subject: ''};
    this.updateSubject = this.updateSubject.bind(this);
    this.updateTimeline = this.updateTimeline.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateTimeline();
  }

  updateSubject(event) {
    this.setState({subject: event.target.value});
  }

  updateTimeline() {
    fetch('/timeline?subject=' + this.state.subject)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(technologies => this.setState({technologies: technologies}));
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <form id="subject" onSubmit={this.updateTimeline}>
        <label>
          Subject:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.subject} onChange={this.updateSubject} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      <Timeline techs={this.state.technologies} />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

However, I figured out that this way each form submission reloads the page (or at least calls the `App` constructor)... which is unfortunate, because the state of `App` gets reset to the empty string (see second line of the constructor). So I tried to add an `event` argument to the `updateTimeline` method, and call `event.preventDefault();` before calling `fetch`:

```
updateTimeline(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch('/timeline?subject=' + this.state.subject)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(technologies => this.setState({technologies: technologies}));
}
```

This gives me `TypeError: event is undefined` in the console. Why is this the case?

Comment: ?? There's no `event` parameter in the definition of `updateTimeline()`

Comment: that is because in `componentDidMount` you are calling it with nothing passed to it.

Comment: As specified in my question, I tried to add an `event` argument to the signature of `updateTimeline`, of course. My problem is that I get `TypeError: event is undefined` even after the `event` argument is added. I can clarify my question with an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSubmit` is very angular, instead of doing it that way change the code like so:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {technologies: [], subject: ''};
    this.updateSubject = this.updateSubject.bind(this);
    this.updateTimeline = this.updateTimeline.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateTimeline();
  }

  updateSubject(event) {
    this.setState({subject: event.target.value});
  }

  updateTimeline() {
    return fetch('/timeline?subject=' + this.state.subject)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(technologies => this.setState({technologies: technologies}));
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <form id="subject">
        <label>
          Subject:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.subject} onChange={this.updateSubject} />
        </label>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.updateTimeline}>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <Timeline techs={this.state.technologies} />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works great, indeed. Thank you! But do you also happen to know why `event.preventDefault();` gives an error in my original solution?

Comment: The onSubmit event does not gets a parameter, do it as you had it but just console.log the event, you’ll see an undefined

Comment: But the React docs use an event argument in the `handleSubmit` method of the `NameForm` example component at this link: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: yes I know, but if you run their own codepen example youll see the same error:
```TypeError: n is null
everypage-1833776b2c0be7ae3094.js:1:327655
    onSuccess https://static.codepen.io/assets/packs/js/everypage-1833776b2c0be7ae3094.js:1
    N https://static.codepen.io/assets/packs/js/everypage-1833776b2c0be7ae3094.js:1
    errorWrapper https://static.codepen.io/assets/packs/js/vendor-0eeab0dfbd1d48f30824.chunk.js:26
    onerror https://static.codepen.io/assets/packs/js/vendor-0eeab0dfbd1d48f30824.chunk.js:26```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @Ernesto that I accepted, I found a more general (and more semantic?) way to obtain the behavior I wanted. This just involves changing the `updateTimeline` method from the code in my original question:

```
updateTimeline(event) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) event.preventDefault();
  fetch('/timeline?subject=' + this.state.subject)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(technologies => this.setState({technologies: technologies}));
  }
```

... this allows to keep the `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` tag, which sounds more semantic to me than a `button` tag. At the same time, this also nicely handles the event of a user hitting return instead of clicking "Submit".